# ModalPopupExtender, its ID and its BehaviorID return a null when called by javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, gridview, modalpopupextender

I've initialized my MPE as follows:

```
<asp:modalpopupextender ID                  ="ModalPopupExtender1"
                    BehaviorID          ="ModalBehavior"
                    runat               ="server"
                    OkControlID         ="btnCancel"
                    CancelControlID     ="btnCancel"
                    TargetControlID     ="dead"
                    PopupControlID      ="Panel1"
                    BackgroundCssClass  ="ModalPopupBG"/>
```

The `ModalPopupExtender`'s `TargetControlID` is:

```
<asp:Button id="dead" runat="server"/>
```

I then assign my gridview row the onclick attribute to call `mpe.Show`:

```cs
switch (e.Row.RowType)
{
    case DataControlRowType.DataRow:
        e.Row.Attributes.Add("onmouseover", "this.style.cursor='hand'");
        e.Row.Attributes.Add("onclick", "ShowPopup()");
        break;
```

My `ShowPopup()` function *within the MasterPage*:

```js
function ShowPopup() {
    var mpe = $find('ModalBehavior');
    mpe.show()
}
```

I've tried many things to try and produce anything other than a null value when the GridView row is clicked, but they have not worked either. Such as:

```cs
switch (e.Row.RowType)
{
    case DataControlRowType.DataRow:
        e.Row.Attributes.Add("onmouseover", "this.style.cursor='hand'");
        e.Row.Attributes.Add("onclick", String.Format("javascript:$find('{0}').show();", ModalPopupExtender1.ClientID));
        break;
```

and this as well

```cs
String.Format("javascript:$find('{0}').show();", ModalPopupExtender1))
String.Format("javascript:$find('{0}').show();", ModalBehavior))
```

When the gridview row is clicked I get the following error:

> Error: 'null' is null or not an object

I have also tried implementing: [Trouble getting a reference to a ModalPopupExtender using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/996910/trouble-getting-a-reference-to-a-modalpopupextender-using-javascript)

```js
function pageLoad() {
    var mpe = $find('ModalBehavior');
    mpe.show();
    debugger;
    $find('ModalBehavior').add_showing(
        function () {
            alert("Modal Popup will be showing");
        }
    );
}
```

but got the same results. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: not sure if this will work; have u tried ModalPopupExtender1.ClientID?!